# «Лучше клоун-директор, чем директор-клоун». Можно ли написать как приложение?

Tags: тире, приложение, или

В предложении: «Никулин однажды сказал: «Лучше клоун-директор, чем директор-клоун». Можно ли написать это как приложение или же лучше с тире: «Лучше клоун – директор, чем директор – клоун» (хотя даже тире сомнительно, но для выделения)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Никулин однажды сказал: «Лучше **клоун-директор**, чем **директор-клоун**».*

Здесь ставится дефис в обоих случаях.

При дефисном написании на втором месте всегда находится **приложение**. Если мы  меняем слова местами, то семантика сочетания  тоже меняется.

Никулин, как я думаю, имел в виду вот что:

Лучше клоун, исполняющий обязанности директора, чем директор, которого (по его характеру и поведению) можно назвать клоуном.